# How can I reassign a Vue ref to another ref and keep reactivity?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-reactivity

My Vue component looks like this (simplified):

```
<template>
  <div @click="loadEvents">{{ loading }}</div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
let loading = ref(false)

loadEvents()
function loadEvents() {
  const res = backendApi.getEvents(selectedDate.value)
  loading = ref(res.loading)
}
</script>
```

The method "backendApi.getEvents" look like this:

```
getEvents() {
  const loading = ref(true)
  axios.get(...).then(r => loading.value = false)
  
  return { loading }
}
```

The issue is that on the initial page load loading correctly displays on the website, first "true" and then "false" after the request has finished. But when the "loadEvents" function is triggered again by clicking on the div, the "loading" value just stays as "false" and is not updated in the DOM. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?
I have tried doing `loading.value = res.loading.value` but this only changes "loading" to "true" and after the request is done it doesn't change to "false".

Comment: FWIW, you're seem to reproduce Suspense functionality by handling loading status manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A short answer would be:

> You cannot reassign a reactive object since the old references will be pointing to the previous object value and reactivity will be lost. All reactive variables should be declared with `const`.

But seems you've overcomplicated the logic. As I understand `loading` should be true when `axios` is loading data (just make your imports right):

```js
<template>
  <div @click="loadEvents">{{ loading }}</div>
</template>

<script setup>

const loading = ref(false);

loadEvents()

async function loadEvents() {
  loading.value = true;
  const results = await backendApi.getEvents(selectedDate.value);
  // use results here
  // ...
  loading.value = false;
}

function getEvents() {
  return axios.get(...);
}

</script>
```

But you can improve that and reuse `loading` moving it the backend api:

```js
// your backend-api.js:

export const loading = ref(false);

export const backendApi = {
  getEvents(){
    return this.callApi(...);
  },
  async callApi(...args){
    loading.value = true;
    const result = await axios.get(...args);
    loading.value = false;
    return result;
  }
};

// your component
<template>
  <div @click="loadEvents">{{ loading }}</div>
</template>

<script setup>

import {loading, backendApi} from './backend-api.js';

loadEvents()

async function loadEvents() {
  const results = await backendApi.getEvents(selectedDate.value);
  // use results here
  // ...
}

</script>
```

**UPDATE**
After some discussion with the author there's some new solution.
The author pointed there's a need for a loading ref per a backend call. Moving loading into the backend api isn't so good, we need some wrapping of api calls and so on. The whole logic becomes NOT agnostic which is looking not perfect. So...
Recently I've become a fan of a setter with some actions and promise setters are my new favorite. Usually I have some module with my Vue utils, so in this case I've created `promiseRef()` which returns a boolean ref with an extra 'promise' property which controls its false/true value. This way we have loading refs independent of any other logic include some backend api as an unnecessary dependence. So the whole setup looks like that:

```
<script setup>
    
  import { backendApi } from './backend-api.js';
  import { promiseRef } from './utils.js'
  
  const loading = promiseRef();

  async function loadEvents(){
     const result = await (loading.promise = backendApi.getEvents());
    // use your results
  }

</script>

<template>
  <button @click="loadEvents">{{ loading }}</button>
</template>
```

backend-api.js:

```
// just emulating some api call
export const backendApi = {
  getEvents(){
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
  }  
}
```

utils.js:

```
import { ref } from 'vue';
export const promiseRef = value => {
  
  const loading = ref(value || false);
  
  let promise;
  
  Object.defineProperty(loading, 'promise', {
    get(){
      return promise;
    },
    set(val){
      loading.value = true;
      (promise = val).then(() => loading.value = false);
    }
  });
  
  return loading;
  
};
```

[**A working Vue3 gist is here!**](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: In your second solution, how could I have a "loading" variable specific to each function? The backendApi has multiple functions which may be called at the same time. In this case I would not be able to differentiate which one is still loading and which one isn't with your solution.

Comment: @Lukas use the first solution then :)

Comment: Well, yes that solution works but then I have duplicated code everywhere where i call a method from the backendApi because I have to set loading before the request and then after the request.

Comment: i will come to a solution later)

Comment: Ok, I'm looking forward to it, thank you :)

Comment: @Lukas you've got it, check the UPDATE section :)

Comment: @Lukas updated the beginning of the answer with some explanation why reassigning wouldn't work

Answer (score 0):

**Composables** is what you're looking for. You can find an [example](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html#async-state-example) with `fetch` in docs.

So use that example to write your composable, then keep the reactivity with the `reactive(useComposable)` and `computed` techniques:

```
import { computed, reactive } from 'vue';
import { useLoadEvents } from './loadEvents.js';

const events = reactive(useLoadEvents());
const loading = computed(() => events.loading);
```

Or do without `computed`, just using `events.loading` in the template directly.